# How to sum numbers in right way in this dictionary(without importing anything)

Tags: python-3.x, file, csv

I couldn't solve this Problem... I have a file 'text.CSV' like this:

```
milk,2.35
bread , 1.95
 chips ,    2.54
milk  ,    2.38
milk,2.31
bread,    1.90
```

def takes file and it should return this:

```
[('bread', '$3.85'), ('chips', '$2.54'), ('milk', '$7.04')]
```

How can i do that? 
My solution:

```
def calculate_expenses(filename):
    #your dict of results :
    dres={}
    file_pointer = open(filename, 'r')
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    f=[]
    for i in data:
        x=i.split(',')
        for j in x:
            a=x[0].strip()
            b=x[1].strip()
            a=a.strip('\n')
            b=b.strip('\n')     
            if a not in dres:
                dres[a]=0
            dres[a]+=float(b)
        f=[]
        #outputting the correct format : as an array of tuples
        for k in sorted(dres.keys()):
            f+=[(k,'${:.2f}'.format(dres[k]))]
    return f
```

It returns:

```
[('bread', '$7.70'), ('chips', '$5.08'), ('milk', '$14.08')]
```

But it must returns:

```
[('bread', '$3.85'), ('chips', '$2.54'), ('milk', '$7.04')]
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def calculate_expenses(filename):
    #your dict of results :
    d={}
    file_pointer = open(filename, 'r')
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    f=[]
    for i in data:
        x=i.split(',')
        a=x[0].strip()
        b=x[1].strip()
        a=a.strip('\n')
        b=b.strip('\n')

        if a not in d:
            d[a]=0
        d[a]+=float(b)
        f=[]
        for k in sorted(d.keys()):
            f+=[(k,'${:.2f}'.format(d[k]))]        
    return f
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Remove `for j in x` and unindent its body.  `j` isn't used and it doubles processing of the body since there are two items in `x`.

You can debug this yourself by printing `a` and `b` in the `for j in x` loop and see the problem.

Also, `.strip()` removes `\n` as well, so the `.strip('\n')` lines aren't needed.